# How to integrate google calendar in kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04

I want all of my google things to pop up in kubuntu giving me notification like my upcoming event from my google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Chromium (or Google Chrome) if you haven't already with `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`
2. Unfortunately, the offical Google Calendar extension doesn't support notifications, but [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-google-c/hkhggnncdpfibdhinjiegagmopldibha?hl=en) does. Sign in and install the extension.
3. Go to Chrome's settings with `chrome://settings/`. Click advanced options check "Continue runnning background apps when Chromium is closed"
4. Go to the settings for the extension by going to `chrome://extensions/` and clicking "Options" under "Checker Plus for Google Calendar". Check "Run in the background when browser is closed". You can also customize notification settings (default is 30 minutes before).
5. Go to "Startup and Shutdown" -> "Autostart" and add `/usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-startup-window` to automatically start Chromium when your computer turns on.

I've tested this on Xubuntu 16.04 and it was able to produce a notification with Chromium windows closed. It should also work on other systems.